# Packer Unable to attach EBS Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer

I am trying to attach additional volume to my ami, this is my builder section,

```
"launch_block_device_mappings": [
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
      "volume_size": 8,
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    },
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "volume_size": 10,
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    }
  ],
  "ami_block_device_mappings": [

     {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "virtual_name": "ephemeral0"
    }
  ]
```

Please help.

Comment: "launch_block_device_mappings": [
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
      "volume_size": 8,
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    },
 {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "volume_size": 10,
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    }
  ],
  "ami_block_device_mappings": [
   
  {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "virtual_name": "ephemeral0"
    }
  ]

Answer (score 2):

This gives you and additional 10Gb disk available for provisioning:

```
{
   "builders" : [
      {
         "type" : "amazon-ebs",
         "instance_type" : "t2.micro",
         "ssh_username" : "ubuntu",
         "ami_name" : "packer-ES-{{timestamp}}",
         "source_ami_filter": {
            "filters": {
              "virtualization-type": "hvm",
              "name": "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*",
              "root-device-type": "ebs"
            },
            "owners": ["099720109477"],
            "most_recent": true
         },
         "launch_block_device_mappings" : [
            {
               "device_name" : "/dev/sdb",
               "delete_on_termination" : true,
               "volume_size" : 10,
               "volume_type" : "gp2"
            }
         ],
         "ami_block_device_mappings" : [
            {
               "device_name" : "/dev/sdb",
               "delete_on_termination" : true,
               "volume_type" : "gp2"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "provisioners": [
     {
       "type": "shell",
       "inline": [
         "lsblk",
         "df -h"
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

Running this you will see:

```
==> amazon-ebs: Connected to SSH!
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with shell script: /var/folders/_t/lsk64yf93xs3slvvtc6b_6mr0000gn/T/packer-shell591343041
    amazon-ebs: NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    amazon-ebs: xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
    amazon-ebs: └─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
    amazon-ebs: xvdb    202:16   0  10G  0 disk
    amazon-ebs: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    amazon-ebs: udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
    amazon-ebs: tmpfs           100M  3.0M   97M   3% /run
    amazon-ebs: /dev/xvda1      7.7G  956M  6.8G  13% /
    amazon-ebs: tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
    amazon-ebs: tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    amazon-ebs: tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    amazon-ebs: tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
==> amazon-ebs: Stopping the source instance...
    amazon-ebs: Stopping instance, attempt 1
```

Verifying the results:

```
env AWS_PROFILE=packer-demo AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1 aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-0a53
cb1f4541b55d4
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "CreationDate": "2018-07-19T09:52:53.000Z",
            "ImageId": "ami-0a53cb1f4541b55d4",
            "ImageLocation": "965990659467/packer-ES-1531993870",
            "ImageType": "machine",
            "Public": false,
            "OwnerId": "965990659467",
            "State": "available",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "Encrypted": false,
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-0e622d809cf0e148a",
                        "VolumeSize": 8,
                        "VolumeType": "gp2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sdb",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "Encrypted": false,
                        "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-0c65cdcdb579f21b4",
                        "VolumeSize": 10,
                        "VolumeType": "standard"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sdc",
                    "VirtualName": "ephemeral1"
                }
            ],
            "EnaSupport": true,
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "Name": "packer-ES-1531993870",
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
            "SriovNetSupport": "simple",
            "VirtualizationType": "hvm"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you don't need to provision anything on sdb you can remove the `launch_device_mappings` section completely and move the `volume_size` into the `ami_device_mappings`.